# How can I change the selected option's text color?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, drop-down-menu

I've changed the selected option's background color to pink.

[image]

However, when I select the option, it sets the color to white, which I don't like.

[image]

How can I change it to something else? I've tried setting the `color` property, but to no avail:

```
select > option:checked {
  background: linear-gradient(pink, pink);
  color: black !important; /* doesn't work */
}
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/o9g8rt23/1/) my fiddle.

Is this possible in Chrome?

**Update:** I peeked at Chrome's default [stylesheet](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/css/html.css) and tried this:

```
select:-internal-list-box:focus option:checked {
    color: black !important;
}
```

But that didn't do the trick. It's greyed out in the dev tools, which means that it's not being applied:

[image]

Comment: Tough to style `select` elements because their styling is determined by the browser and each browser treats them differently. I would suggest either faking a select element if you want to achieve this level of customization or just living with the default styling.

Comment: Does this become more doable given that I only care about Chrome?

Comment: I don't think is possible with out using a custom select. The color is actually black but chrome overrides this underneath the hood. Note that it only turns white when the select is `:focused` as soon as you click outside of the select it is the color that you told it to be.

Comment: I think even with Chrome you're going to need to fake a select box if you want this level of customization. There might be some hacky way to do it, but probably not worth the effort.